# Helix PanormaCube3D doesn't ignore light

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm using PanormaCube3D as a skybox for a scene I'm creating. If the lights are off and Ambient is set to white, It works flawlessly. But as soon as there are more lights added, the skybox is lit and has distinctive brighterr and darker sides.
Hwo do I make the skybox ignore light?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope I just gave up. As a personal tip, just completely refrain from using wpf 3d honestly, look for an alternative or just learn glsl and use an opengl renderwindow. Its how I ended up solving it